# Intent ACTION_VIEW does not found an activity to handle the request, even if chrome is present

Tags: android, google-chrome, actionview

The following code works in most cels, opening a page in a browser:

```
       Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        String dataType = getMimeType(url);
        if (dataType == null || dataType.equals("")) {
            dataType = "*/*";
        }
        browserIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), dataType);

        PackageManager packageManager = myActivity.getPackageManager();
        List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(browserIntent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
        if (isIntentSafe) {
            myActivity.startActivityForResult(browserIntent, -1001);

        } else { ... }
```

But there are some celphones where chrome or other browser is present in the celphone, and even so queryIntentActivities does not recognize it returning empty array.

There is some setting user must configure in order to recognize chrome (o other viewer) by the queryIntentActivities function?

Comment: Well what is the value of dataType that is used? Why do you think browsers are invoked? You should also tell the value of that url of course.

Comment: @greenapps. <br/> Sorry: dataType = "*/*" ; url = https://www.pagina12.com.ar/93878-los-sueldos-mas-golpeados-de-la-region. <br/> Browsers are not invoked if activities.size() == 0, which means that  the program does not found an intent to handle the request. If i force the call when this hapenns, an exception arise. Usually  in mot phones, _(activities.size() > 0)_ so this problem does not ocurrs, becaouse the program founds several browsers , so i call the intent and it works fine.<br/> But in **some phones** I get _activities.size==0_, **even when chrome is installed in the phone**

Comment: That is a non existing mime type. So what do you expect? If you want to start browsers than use "text/html". And you posted an url in a way the protocoll is invisible.